# Get html output of react file for a given file containing import statements

Tags: c#, reactjs

I'm trying to get the HTML output from a react file, inside C#. I've tried with this sample 
[github.com/reactjs/React.NET - React.Sample.ConsoleApp](https://github.com/reactjs/React.NET/blob/master/src/React.Sample.ConsoleApp/Program.cs). It work well with basic react components, but fails to compile when there are import/exports, which in my case are important. In some of the issues on github they say that React.Net doesn't support such statements. Is there any other alternative way or tool to accomplish this? We are using webpack/babel when building our files.

Here is my original js file:

```
import React from "react";
import { NoRecords } from "ui/Bootstrap";

export class NotesList extends React.Component {    
    generateNotesList() {
        let notes = this.state.notes;

        // No data message
        if (typeof notes === "undefined" || notes === null || notes.length === 0) {
            return (
                <NoRecords text="No notes to display" />
            );
        }

        return (
            <ul className="conversation-list">
                {notes.map((note, i) =>
                    <li key={i}>{note.Note}</li>
                )}
            </ul>
        );
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="notes-wrapper">
                <div className="notes">
                    {this.generateNotesList()}
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have an app in production that uses [ASP.NET Javascript services](https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices/) to render my React app on the server. To do this you will need to make sure your babel / webpack output transpiles your import statements and that the transpiled code is whats read by your server renderer.

There are lots of docs on the github describing how to do it but I can provide some examples if you'd like.

I think the issue you are facing right now has to do with not transpiling the code before your .NET code picks it up.

Comment: Sure, and example would be nice. Currently we can transpile the code but on the .net jint side imports from node modules are failing.

Comment: @x-freestyler are you using webpack to compile it? Just saw this issue. https://github.com/reactjs/React.NET/issues/311

Comment: When testing with react.net no, but in the real project yes we do use webpack and babel to transpile our code

Comment: That's probably your problem, react.net will need to read the transpiled code to avoid the import issue.